# Sending email with Python and smtplib getting two duplicate emails

Tags: python, smtplib, os.path

Python newb here.  I am trying to send an email after processing a command.  When I test, I am receiving two duplicate emails vs. 1.  My code is below.

```
import smtplib
import os.path

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText("The report at *link* has been updated")

msg['Subject'] = "Test Report Notification **TEST**"

#put your host and port here 
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('###########.net:465')
s.login('system@#########','#####') 
s.sendmail('system@#####.com','bryan#########', msg.as_string())
s.quit()
print("done")
```

Thanks in advance.  I really have tried researching.

Comment: I've got the same problem -- have you found a solution for this?

Comment: same here, any fix?